# EEA pre settled status marriage and retained rights

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu-spouses, uk-citizenship

If a third-country citizen marries an EEA national in the UK with pre-settled status in 2022. What visa will they apply for. And what about retained rights after 3 years rule? Will this policy continue for new couples after 2022 or not?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you think you may not want people to be able to see your question in the future, don’t post it in the first place. Vandalising it doesn’t make it disappear, it is of course still visible to everyone with access rights to edited posts, and is likely to be reverted. Plus users may be less inclined to bother to answer further questions you may post.

Answer (score 3):

Under the terms of the [Withdrawal Agreement](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:12019W/TXT(02)&from=EN) only relationships established before the end of the transition period open special rights for members of the family of an EEA citizen. However, marriage is not the only type of relationship that's relevant so if the couple had formed earlier, the spouse might still qualify for an easier visa on the basis of this “durable relationship”.

All this is detailed in article 10:

> **Personal scope**
>
> 1. Without prejudice to Title III, this Part shall apply to the following persons:
>
> (a)  Union citizens who exercised their  right to reside in the United Kingdom in accordance with Union law before the end of  the transition period and continue to reside there thereafter;
>
> […]
>
> (e)  family members of  the persons referred to in points (a) to (d), provided that they fulfil one of the following conditions:
>
> (i)  they resided in the host State in accordance with Union law before the end of the transition period and continue to reside there thereafter;
>
> (ii)  they  were  directly  related  to  a  person  referred  to  in  points  (a)  to  (d)  and  resided  outside  the  host  State  before  the end  of  the  transition  period,  provided  that  they  fulfil  the  conditions  set  out  in  point  (2)  of  Article  2  of  Directive 2004/38/EC  at  the  time  they  seek  residence  under  this  Part  in  order  to  join  the  person  referred  to  in  points  (a) to (d) of this paragraph;
>
> […]
>
> 4. Without prejudice to any right to residence which the persons concerned may have in their own right, the host State shall,  in  accordance  with  its  national  legislation  and  in  accordance  with  point  (b)  of  Article  3(2)  of  Directive  2004/38/EC, facilitate  entry  and  residence  for  the  partner  with  whom  the  person  referred  to  in  points  (a)  to  (d)  of  paragraph  1  of  this Article  has  a  durable  relationship,  duly  attested,  where  that  partner  resided  outside  the  host  State  before  the end  of  the transition  period,  provided  that  the  relationship  was  durable  before  the  end  of  the  transition  period  and  continues at  the time the partner seeks residence under  this Part.

Regarding marriage, note that tarticle 10(1)(e)(ii) reads “they **were** related”, i.e. the marriage must have existed before Brexit. It's only in that case that EU freedom of movement rights can cover a spouse who wasn't already present in the UK, which means someone marrying in 2022 wouldn't be covered by this provision.

The same logic applies to point (4): Only a relationship that qualified as durable before the end of the transition period can be invoked. It could however be useful if the two spouses were already in a relationship long before marrying. On the other hand, if their relationship started after Brexit or even shortly before, the only option left would be the regular UK immigration rules.

Comment: If the relationship would have qualified as a "durable relationship" on or before the end of the transition period, the couple ought to be able to apply on that basis. It wouldn't make sense for the marriage to reduce the rights derived from the relationship: https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/eligibility.  Also, there are some people for whom the June 30 deadline does not apply, though it doesn't seem that any of these cases is likely to apply here: https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/join-EU-EEA-Swiss-family-member

Comment: @phoog That's true, it's actually covered in the same article (point 4 further down) but I discounted it because I was focusing on the fact that the relationship described in the question (the marriage) was established after the end of the transition period. You're obviously absolutely right that someone marrying in 2022 may very well have been in a durable relationship for some time before that. I will rephrase the answer.